# IndexError at /delta/ - list index out of range - Django

Tags: python, django

The user selects two aircraft to compare from the list page. However I get the following error: ***IndexError at /delta/ list index out of range***.

It's complaining about this line in particular:

```
first_value = getattr(aircraft_to_compare[0], key)
```

Is there an obvious error that I'm making here?

**View**

```
def aircraft_delta(request):
  ids = [id for id in request.GET.get('ids') if id != ',']
  aircraft_to_compare = Aircraft.objects.filter(id__in=ids)

  property_keys = ['name', 'manufacturer', 'aircraft_type', 'body', 'engines',
                   'image', 'cost','maximum_range','passengers','maximum_altitude','cruising_speed',
                   'fuel_capacity','description','wing_span','length']

  column_descriptions = {
    'image': '',
    'name': 'Aircraft',
    'maximum_range': 'Range (NM)',
    'passengers': 'Passengers',
    'cruising_speed': 'Max Speed (kts)',
    'fuel_capacity': 'Fuel Capacity',
    'aircraft_type': 'Type',
    'body':'Body',
    'engines':'Engines',
    'cost':'Cost',
    'maximum_altitude':'Maximum Altitude',
    'description':'Description',
    'manufacturer':'Manufacturer',
    'wing_span':'Wing Span (FT)',
    'length':'Total Length (FT)'
  }

  data = []

  for key in property_keys:
    row = [column_descriptions[key]]


    first_value = getattr(aircraft_to_compare[0], key)
    second_value = getattr(aircraft_to_compare[1], key)

    if key not in ['image', 'name']:
        delta = abs(first_value - second_value)
    else:
        delta = ''

    row.append(first_value)
    row.append(delta)
    row.append(second_value)

    data.append(row)

  return render(request, 'aircraft/aircraft_delta.html', {
    'data': data
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

**IndexError at /delta/ list index out of range.** means that there is not data that was found by your model. You might want to look into your db to see whether those `Ids` exist or not. As per your code, there are no errors, so plz look at `Aircraft.objects.filter(id__in=ids)` a little more in deep.

Also its a good approach to use `len(aircraft_to_compare)` to check whether any data is present or not.

Hope this helps.

Comment: How do I check whether the id's exist or not? And what do you mean look a little deeper? I don't know whats going on cos it was working before

Comment: I am guessing your database might have gotten updated. So when I said that the id's don't exist, what I meant was you are looking for values which are not in the db.

Comment: If they dont exist what exactly do I do then? I've created new objects and the ID's are there but they're not being picked up. Theres a mistake in the code somewhere but I don't know where it is

Comment: Could you show the output of `ids` line 2? I might be able to help you debug this further.

Comment: Aircraft.objects.filter(id=5)
<Aircraft: Boeing 777-300ER>]

Aircraft.objects.filter(id=6)
 [<Aircraft: A340-600>]

Comment: It doesn't start from 0?

Comment: Could you try this Aircraft.objects.filter(id__in=[5,6]), does that show you the correct response? Also ids is the list? I wanted to see how your list looks like?

Comment: [<Aircraft: A340-600>, <Aircraft: Boeing 777-300ER>] <--This is the result

Comment: Ok, what about **ids** in `id__in=ids` ? What does this list consist of?

Comment: Okay, so this is what happened. When I wrote "Aircraft.objects.filter(id__in=[5,6])" in the view, the template displayed the comparison. But, when when I changed it back to "id__in=ids", it threw the list index out of range error. So its not picking it up dynamically for some reason

Comment: Yup. What that tells me is that **ids** in `id__in=ids` is doing something wrong. Could you check whether the type is correct or not? Perhaps, you are getting the list with ['5','6'] instead of [5,6]. See the difference? Perhaps parsing into integer is the solution. Could you do a print on **ids**?

Comment: `print ids` for python 2 and `print (ids)` for python 3. I would suggest that you learn how to use `pdb` as well. Its pretty efficient and easy to use and many people don't know about it.

Comment: With the code above can you show what you mean? I'm actually quite confused becuase its not printing anything

Comment: You need to add a print according to your version. So try `print 'here' `. See if that works. Then do a print of the ids. If nothing is shown on ids then your ids is none.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141975/discussion-between-pansul-bhatt-and-hosh-adf).

Answer (score 0):

You may not have found any records in the query

```
aircraft_to_compare = Aircraft.objects.filter(id__in=ids)
```

Check the length of `aircraft_to_compare` or use `try...except` block while accessing items from that queryset.

Comment: I've tried the try and except. funny thing is, it used to work. but not for some reason it doesnt

Comment: @HoshAdf, it should work. It also matters what do you do in `except` part. So what do you mean it doesn't work.

Comment: can you give me an example of what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

In Views,
You are creating a list `data=[]`, then you are appending some values in that list. So the problem is when the list is appended to its max length there is no space left to append more values "list out of range". You can try to make the list empty after each operation(comparison) using `data.clear() .`